# Is it possible to provide a generic type constraint to a List in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
interface Conditional{
   fun isEligible(): Boolean
}

class Super()

class A(): Super(), Conditional
class B(): Super()
```

I would like to create a list that only contains `Super` subclasses that have implemented `Conditional` interface. *(Just to help me with some compile-time static type checking)*

Compiler would allow me to create this:

`val conditionals: List<Super : Conditional> = listOf(A())`

But it would not allow me to create this:

`val conditionals: List<Super : Conditional> = listOf(A(), B())`

I understand you can use generics with classes and function declarations, but how about value declarations?

EDIT
I tried the following but type inference doesn't work well, it seems I'd need to do casting to a specific interface
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible without creating a common class extending from both. Another option would be to have a custom `listOf` function, but it doesn't scale well if you need the same trick elsewhere: `fun <A> superConditionalsOf(vararg elements: A) where A : Super, A : Conditional = listOf(*elements)`

Comment: @gpunto this would allow constructing the list, but it doesn't offer type inference down the road.  For example, if you want to `filter` on the result, it infers the underlying items as `Any` :(

Comment: @ArtursVancans I just tried before suggesting the same thing, and type inference works fine with this custom listOf

Comment: Look at the screenshot in my answer, I did assign to a variable and it worked fine. Did you specify explicitly the return type of the function as `List<A>`? This might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, intersection types are not denotable yet in Kotlin code (see [KT-13108](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108)).

However, they are internally supported by the compiler, so you can get away with some generic constructs in some cases.

One option is to use a custom `listOf` specifically for these types:

```kotlin
fun <T> listOfConditionalSuper(vararg elements: T): List<T> where T: Super, T: Conditional =
    listOf(*elements)
```

You will get proper type inference then:
[image: proper autocomplete]

Comment: Seems like it's working. I'll play around with this to see if everything behaves as expected. 